# Dependencies in MVC 6 application of multilayered solution

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am developing a solution that includes data layer, business layer and UI layer (MVC 6 application).

MVC application works only with interfaces of business layer. It doesn't know anything about services (implementation of business layer) and data layer. It only has reference to project that contains business layer interfaces.

I have an issue that connected with dependencies. According to my opinion, I must add all dependencies (including repositories and services) into `Startup.cs` file, but MVC 6 application mustn't have references to repositories or services.

How can I add all my dependencies without adding references?

Answer (score 0):

The MVC6 application **must** reference your service and repository implementations, either directly or indirectly. The thing it *should not* do is construct instances of these implementations from your `Controller` components.

So in other words, it is **okay** to do this in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
  services.AddInstance<IServiceOrRepo, ServiceOrRepoImpl>();
}
```

It is **not** okay to do this in any controller:

```
private readonly IServiceOrRepo _serviceOrRepo;

public MyController() {
  this._serviceOrRepo = new ServiceOrRepoImpl();
}
```

But either way, at runtime, the controller must be able to resolve the actual `ServiceOrRepoImpl` implementation instance from one of its referenced assemblies (via the IoC container of course). This means the assembly or project that contains the implementation must be referenced by the MVC project either directly or indirectly.

Comment: Can I add all dependencies in separated project `DependencyResolver` and use it in MVC project (call methods of `DependencyResolver` to add all dependencies  in `Startup.cs`)?

Comment: Certainly. You could probably even do the registration using extension methods defined in the DependencyResolver assembly, like `services.AddApplicationDependencies()`.